# Java method Inputstream.read(byte[] buffer) is slower than Blob java.sql.Blob.getBytes

Tags: java, postgresql, blob

I am trying to download a blob from postgres.

I have two methods:

1. Downloads a blob using **blob.getBytes(pos, BLOB_BUFFER_SIZE)**

   ```
    private static void downloadBlob(HttpServletResponse response, java.sql.Blob blob) throws 
    IOException, SQLException {
       try (ServletOutputStream outputStream = response.getOutputStream()) {
           outputStream.flush();
           byte[] buffer;
           int bufferLength;
           long pos = 1;
           do {
               buffer = blob.getBytes(pos, BLOB_BUFFER_SIZE);
               bufferLength = buffer.length;
               pos += bufferLength;
               outputStream.write(buffer);
               outputStream.flush();
           }
           while (bufferLength > 0);
       }
       catch (ClientAbortException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
       }
   }
   ```
2. Downloads a blob using **streamContent.read(buffer)**

   ```
    private static void writeStreamToResponse(HttpServletResponse response, InputStream streamContent) throws IOException
    {
    try (ServletOutputStream outputStream = response.getOutputStream()) {
        outputStream.flush();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[BLOB_BUFFER_SIZE];
        int bytesRead;
        do {
            bytesRead = streamContent.read(buffer);
            outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            outputStream.flush();
        }
        while (bytesRead != -1);

    }
    catch (ClientAbortException error) {
        LOGGER.error(error.getMessage());
    }
    finally {
        streamContent.close();
    }
   ```

   }

**I have a one question:**
Why does reading an array of bytes (getBytes()) work much faster than reading from a inputStream (inputStream.read(buffer)) ?

Reading streamContent.read(buffer) takes a very long time.

Comment: Why are you doing this manually?  There are libraries, namely Hibernate, that handle database abstraction.  Use them.

Comment: Assuming the column is defined as `bytea` then Postgres can not really stream the contents. You always get everything. So my assumption(!!) would be that the driver already reads everything as a `byte[]` array. Using `getOutputStream()` then needs to convert that array to a stream which is imposes an overhead. But `getBytes()` simply returns that array the driver already has. But if you want to be certain, you will have to inspect the driver's source code.